# UIWebview :: Text :: HTML :: JS

Tags: iphone

1- i load a text from a txt file
2- i show it into a html "file" 
3- problem :
3-a : this code works :
i create my page by code and i insert my text

```
myText = ... loaded from an array of texts ...;
 NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
 "<head> \n"
 "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
 "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: 1.0f + 'em'; color:#FFF;}\n"
 "</style> \n"
 "</head> \n"
 "<body id=\"myid\">%@</body> \n"
 "</html>", @"Arial", myText];
 [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
```

3-b but this one does not work :
i load a html page already created and i inject my text into using JS :

```
myText = ... loaded from an array of texts ...;
 [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"myid\").innerHTML = \"%@\";", myText]];
```

3-c but this one working :
same as 3-b but i init my text with a string in the code itself :

```
myText = @"hello all";
 [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"myid\").innerHTML = \"%@\";", myText]];
```

any help to understand what's wrong with 3-b ?

thank you

Comment: I wonder if the text you load from an external file contains characters like " ' \ and so on.

Comment: in my texts there are NON aschii char as ô é à ç è
there are also '

Comment: but if as in 3-c
i init my string with these char, it is still working : 
myText = @"hel' lôo al'l èàçé";